# Are there any problems resulting in connecting 2 8 port ethernest switches together?

Tags: switch

Are there any problems resulting when connecting two 8 port ethernet switches together.

Comment: Aside from "no" I'm not so sure how we can help.  Can you elaborate on what you feel might go wrong with doing that?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no.  Assuming you're using a single ethernet cable to connect the two.

If you want to use multiple cables/ports, you'll need to configure a LAG.

You'll also want to make sure that loops are prevented using STP or something similar.

Comment: Also need to consider the makes/models of the switches. If they are managed Cisco switches for example and non-trunk interfaces being connected, he may find the ports err-disabled due to bpdu being sent/received...